# Get id of the element on click event and make an ajax call with id as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have my code is

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="1"  href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/InchatroomController/LikeMessage/1" style=""> </a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="2"  href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/InchatroomController/LikeMessage/2" style=""> </a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="3"  href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/InchatroomController/LikeMessage/3" style=""> </a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="4"  href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/InchatroomController/LikeMessage/4" style=""> </a>
```

I need to get id of the  tag on click event and make an ajax call which sends the id as parameter to the controller

Comment: Your questions isn't clear enough. Did you mean you need to sent out an ajax call to invoke the controller method when clicking on the <a> link?

Comment: i need to get id in tag a when click it and sent id to controller

Comment: See if my answer helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        // Fetch the id of the element clicked
        var elemId = event.target.id;
        // Sending ajax call to server with id of the clicked element
        $.ajax({
                url: 'yourControllerUrl',
                type: 'POST',
                data: jQuery.param({ id: elemId}) ,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    // success javascript code
                },
                error: function () {
                    // failure javascript code
                }
        }); 
    });
});
```